# Setting content below image

Tags: html, css

Is there anyway I can position my div content stuff to go below image.I don't want to give padding to wrap class as no one know how big the image would be so I need a solution where text goes below to image as mentioned in html structure.

```css
.parent {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: static;
}

.wrap {}

.child {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  top: 30px
}

div {
  height: 400px;
}

body {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"><img src="https://images.mapsofworld.com/around-the-world/Chinese-economy-faces-tough-times.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="wrap">stuff</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about not positioning `.child`.

Comment: what to you mean by text goes below the image and . in the output you are hiding the text div ?? tell me what's your requirement..just upload some sample output you need

Answer (score 0):

Position wrap inside child

```css
html, body { padding: 0; margin:0; }
.parent {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: static;
}

.wrap {}

.child {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  top: 30px
}

div {
  height: 400px;
}

body {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"><img src="https://images.mapsofworld.com/around-the-world/Chinese-economy-faces-tough-times.jpg" />
    <div class="wrap">stuff</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Transform: Translate()` to move it under, inside the parent `<div>`. I did this myself with a table and input fields inside a `<div>`